# Computing the average of a dataset with respect to a threshold in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to compute the average of some data samples entered one at a time. I will then set a threshold bound to compare and only count values greater than the threshold. Then I would display a count of the values less than the threshold and the compute the average of the values. My problem is my average computation is off and I'm clueless as to way in fixing the issue. The MATLAB code I wrote is shown below.

```
%% enter
thresh    = input('Please enter the threshold value: ');
datatotal = input('Please enter the number of data samples to be entered: ');       
data      = input('Please enter a data sample: ');
sum       = 0;
count     = 1;

while count < datatotal

   data = input('Please enter a data sample: ');  
   if data > thresh
      threshdata = data;
      for m = 1:threshdata-1        
         sum = sum + m;
      end
   end
   count = count + 1;
end

average = sum/ length(m);

fprintf('The average of %d valid data samples is %.2f volts.\n', m, average);
% code here
```

Comment: What is the value of `length(m)` after your `while` loop is finished?

Comment: Why do you add all the values from 1:threshdata and not just threshdata?

Comment: I would guess once the data that is greater than the threshold has been established. It would be known and thus I used a for loop to loop through each single data and add it in a manner of a running sum. Apologies, length m shouldn't be there due to the fact ,we are not storing this in a vector. I tried using threshdata instead of 1:threshdata, it still didn't work. Thanks

Comment: @Pharcyde So what *is* the actual formula you're using? You say you're counting the values *greater* than the threshold, but then displaying a count of values *less* than the threshold. Have you tried using the debugger to step through your code and see if the values are what you expect at each iteration?

Comment: I figured it out, thanks. i ended removing the for loop and applying a second counter iteration after the line that sets the data to the threshdata and the use that second counter as the denominator to get the average.  it worked.